# GWT Application loading time

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I am using GWT 2.0.3 with ext version.When I run the application its take some time to load.As much as I know It take time to load some JS file (Not sure about it).For slow internet connection it wiil take more time.

I want to know what exactly GWT application do while loading.If it is loading some JS file the is there ant way to reudce loading time by dividing JS file or by nay other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a GWT application loads, it loads all js files contained in your html host page, what means everything client side related is loaded.

To optimize this GWT introduced code splitting some time ago. You can check it [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html). The basic idea is to divide your application in logical parts, when a user wants to access to another part, its loaded on demand.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up web app loading time, indeed split points are a first step.

But check as well this tool:
http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com

Slowness can also come from uncompressed pictures for instance.

Also, when you compile your GWT app, ensure you use "OBFUSCATED" mode for your compiled javascript, which makes it significantly smaller.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#Why_is_my_GWT-generated_JavaScript_gibberish?

Now if you are using Apache HTTPD as web server, Google has released a wonderful Apache module that implements web app best practices out of the box:
http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/